# The constructor name is always 'Object' after compiled to JavaScript from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have TypeScript code to read instance's class name like this:

```js
this.constructor.name
```

It works well in TypeScript in local development environment because using ts-node.

But after it goes into production, which use node to run the compiled javascript code, the aforementioned code would always produce:

```
Object
```

How to keep getting the class name behavior both in TypeScript and JavaScript?

`tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2017",
      "module": "commonjs" ,
      "declaration": true ,
      "outDir": "./lib" ,
      "strict": true ,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings/*"] ,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "typings"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/test/*"]
}
```

The build command is as follows:

`package.json`:

```
"script": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
}
```

Comment: A quick check with just the basic typescript compiler seems to indicate that `this.constructor.name` works correctly, but various things can mess with the names. Could you include how you are building your project, including any relevant configs such as `tsconfig.json` or `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I ran your build on
`class A { public printName() { console.log(this.constructor.name); } }`
`new A().printName();`
and it printed `A`. Do you have any specific examples of when it doesn't work?